# Rest Assured: Why do I get IllegalStateException exception?

Tags: rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am in the process of studying Rest-Assured framework.

I am using http://ziptasticapi.com free API for my drills.

When I call:

```
final static String BASE_URI = "http://ziptasticapi.com/";

final static String ADAK_ZIP_CODE = "99546"; //{"country":"US","state":"AK","city":"ADAK"}
final static String ATKA_ZIP_CODE = "99547";

public static final String GET_METHOD = "GET";
    RestAssured.baseURI = BASE_URI;

    String responseString = when().get(ADAK_ZIP_CODE).then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .and()
            .extract()
            .asString();

    System.out.println(responseString);
```

I get the following string:

> {"country":"US","state":"AK","city":"ADAK"}

as responseString value.

When I am trying:

```
 RestAssured.baseURI = BASE_URI;      

 ZipData zipdata = when().get(ADAK_ZIP_CODE).then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .and()
            .extract()
            .as(ZipData.class);

public class ZipData {

    public String country;
    public String state;
    public String city;

}
```

I crash on :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot parse object because no
>   supported Content-Type was specified in response. Content-Type was
>   'text/html;charset=UTF-8'.

Why is that? Could it be the rest returns an Html and not Json? How do I handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind that REST Assured is a HTTP client primarily designed for testing HTTP APIs. So let me highlight that you shouldn't use REST Assured for anything other than testing.

---

Looks like the endpoint you are attempting to consume is returning a JSON document in the response payload, but the value of the `Content-Type` header is `text/html;charset=UTF-8`, so REST Assured cannot parse the response as a JSON document and convert it to an instance of `ZipData`. That's not what you expect from a sound HTTP API.

You could work around it and write a [filter](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/usage#filters) to override the `Content-Type` header, as show below:

```java
public class OverrideContentTypeFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification requestSpec,
                           FilterableResponseSpecification responseSpec,
                           FilterContext ctx) {

        Response next = ctx.next(requestSpec, responseSpec);
        return new ResponseBuilder().clone(next).setContentType(ContentType.JSON).build();
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```java
ZipData zipdata =
        given()
            .filter(new OverrideContentTypeFilter())
        .when()
            .get(uri)
        .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .extract()
            .as(ZipData.class);
```

Comment: Also had to add jackson-databind dependency and it worked. Thanks!!